# How do I calculate how much CPU, RAM, energy is required to run a specific Python program?

Tags: python, cpu-usage, ram, energy

Suppose we want to find out how much energy, CPU and RAM are being used in Python to find out the factorial of a positive integer. I used the code below but it is not working.

**MWE:**

```
from __future__ import print_function
import psutil

n=5
fact=1
for i in range(1,n+1):
    fact=fact*i
print fact

print('CPU  % used:', psutil.cpu_percent())
print('physical memory  % used:', psutil.virtual_memory())  # physical memory usage
print('memory % used:', psutil.virtual_memory()[2])
```

Comment: I do not think you can measure how much energy you use from inside of python program. I do not think it will have access to every sensor that reports energy usage of your computer.

Comment: @  MichaelBykhovtsev Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [`psutil.Process(pid=None)`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#process-class). Note on the documentation:

> If pid is omitted current process pid ([`os.getpid`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getpid)) is used.

Therefore, you can simply do:

```py
import psutil


process = psutil.Process()
memory = process.memory_percent()
cpu = process.cpu_percent()

print(memory, cpu)
```

The above is for memory and CPU percentage use only. I recommend reading further into the documentation to figure out exactly what you need.